# raise KeyError(key) in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to ready file path from file called config.ini using following code.

```
root_drive = r'P:\scripts\\'
config_object = ConfigParser()
config_object.read(root_drive+'Scripts\config.ini')
filepath= config_object["FILEPATH"]
'''SETUP VARIABLES'''
s=datetime.datetime.now()
out_file=filepath["output"]+r'\Final Output File for '+s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S')+'.xlsx'
log_file= filepath["processlog"]+r'\LogFile_{0}.log'.format(s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S'))
```

My config.ini file looks like this containing filepaths.

```
[FILEPATH]
input = P:\scripts\Input
processed = P:\scripts\Processed
output = P:\scripts\Output
processlog = P:\scripts\LogFiles
dupes = P:\scripts\Processed\DuplicateInput
```

Error I am getting is :

```
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'FILEPATH'
```

Why is the FILEPATH not working?

I hardcoded the paths but doesn't work.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I can't reproduce the issue. It seems that the error is due to the path of your _config.ini_. Try with root_drive `root_drive = r'P:\scripts\config.ini'`, then `config_object.read(root_drive)`.

Comment: @Shweta even when you hard code the **config_object["FILEPATH"]** you still get a key error for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that your config file does actually exist at `P:\scripts\\Scripts\config.ini`. I suspect that you have an extra `\` in the `root_drive` component.

```py
import os
from configparser import ConfigParser
root_drive = r'P:\scripts\\' # This should be r'P:\scripts\'
config_path = root_drive + 'Scripts\config.ini'
if not os.path.isfile(config_path):
    print(f"{config_path} does not exist!")
config_object = ConfigParser()
config_object.read(config_path)
filepath= config_object["FILEPATH"]
'''SETUP VARIABLES'''
s=datetime.datetime.now()
out_file=filepath["output"]+r'\ Final Output File for '+s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S')+'.xlsx'
log_file= filepath["processlog"]+r'\LogFile_{0}.log'.format(s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S'))
```